# How can I remove the disabled icon on a button when hovering?

Tags: html, css

For react button

```
<Button
  onClick={() => this.clickHandler()}
  disabled={isTrue}
>
  Enter
</Button>
```

When I hover the button, here's a circle icon with a line how can I remove this?
[image]

Comment: This isn't a React question. Either your browser or a style library is adding that icon, and you need to use CSS to change it.

Comment: See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#buttons-disabled for an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this using css

first attatch a class name to your button

```
<Button className={ isTrue && "disabled-btn" } > Enter <Button>
```

Then add the following Css

```
disabled-btn:hover {
  background: #dddddd;    // change the styling according to your need
}
```

and don't forget to import the css file in your Component.